# How to read from file using see and putting the content into a list in Prolog?

Tags: io, prolog

I am studying Prolog using SWI Prolog and I am finding many difficulties about how to read textual data from a file and printing it on the screen using **see** built in predicate.

I have this program that read the content of a file using the **open** predicate in read modality and a **Stream** associated to this file

```
readFile(InputFile, TextList):- open(InputFile, read, Stream),
                                readCharacter(Stream, TextList),
                                close(Stream),
                                !.

readCharacter(Stream,[]):- at_end_of_stream(Stream).    %condizione di uscita


readCharacter(Stream,[Char|Rest]):-
                                 get0(Stream,Char),
                                 readCharacter(Stream,Rest).
```

This is pretty simple but I am asking if I can implement the same behavior using the **see** predicate to change the input stream from user (the console) to another file, and later close to this stream (coming back to user) using **seen** built in predicate:

I was thinking to something like this:

```
readFileSee(InputFile, TextList) :- see(InputFile),
                                    read_from_file(TextList),
                                    seen. %or maybe: see(user).
```

But now, differently to the previous working example, I have not the **Stream** variable on which call the **get0** predicate, so I don't know how gon on.

Someone can help me to solve this problem reading the content of InputFile and putting this content into TextList list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edinburgh I/O is convenient, but a bit glitchy because it works on the principle of screwing around with global state. The idea is to use reading and writing predicates that take no stream parameter. You pretend you're reading from standard input or writing to standard output. Then, before calling the code that works this way, you change the global input or output stream to the files you want to read or write.

So, suppose you want to read three atomic characters. You might write:

```
read_three([A,B,C]) :- get_char(A), get_char(B), get_char(C).
```

This works with standard input:

```
?- read_three(X).
|: abc

X = [a, b, c].
```

To make it work with a file instead, you wrap this with a `seeing(OldStream), see(filename), ..., seen, see(OldStream)`, where your code goes in the `...` portion. For instance, we could do this:

```
read_three(Filename, Three) :- 
    % the wrapper to switch files
    seeing(OldStream), see(Filename), 

    % your code
    read_three(Three), 

    % the wrapper to switch back
    seen, see(OldStream).
```

Using it, you need to have a filename to read from, but it might look like this:

```
?- read_three('clone.sh', X).
X = [#, !, /].
```

The key here is that you're not passing an explicit stream instance around, you're just relying on predicates that implicitly use standard input or output to do their job. In other words, none of your predicates should have a `Stream` parameter if they're using Edinburgh I/O, nor should you be using `open/3`.

The wrapper for writing is similar: `telling(OldStream), tell(Filename), ..., told, tell(OldStream).`

Comment: Thank you, but I must insist that many of the other folks are substantially more knowledgeable than I am.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `library(pio)` instead: Describe the file contents with a DCG and then use `phrase_from_file/2` to apply it to a file.

Comment: mmm I think that the question was another !!! If is it possible do the same thing using see and without using other library

Comment: Well, since you also added the tag "declarative" to your question, I thought you are interested in a modern declarative solution as well. And if you are not, it may still be useful for others. `see/1` is outdated and should not be used any more.

Comment: Tnx, I will provide to study it...I am beginner in Prolog and declarative world...this is my first time that I study something like it for an universitary exame and I don't know very well how I have to moove in this world :-)